# Problem with the PIL (pillow) library , ImportError: dlopen.... Reason: image not found

Tags: python, macos, jupyter-notebook, anaconda3

Actually this not a question , its the solution that worked for me and i wanted to help others that might have been throught the same experience.
So i had a problem in anaconda that i didnt know the source of it , so i ended up having to reinstall everything , during the reinstallation i also had to reinstall the libraries that was one installed by the previous conda that i had ( libraries like : pandas, numpy , pillow ... ext ) , the problem is even tho i installed pillow using this command : conda install pillow ,and installed matplotlib  i kept getting error when i try to call the matplotlib library:

```
   File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PIL/Image.py:84
     75 MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS = int(1024 * 1024 * 1024 // 4 // 3)
     78 try:
     79     # If the _imaging C module is not present, Pillow will not load.
     80     # Note that other modules should not refer to _imaging directly;
     81     # import Image and use the Image.core variable instead.
     82     # Also note that Image.core is not a publicly documented interface,
     83     # and should be considered private and subject to change.
---> 84     from . import _imaging as core
     86     if __version__ != getattr(core, "PILLOW_VERSION", None):
     87         msg = (
     88             "The _imaging extension was built for another version of Pillow or PIL:\n"
     89             f"Core version: {getattr(core, 'PILLOW_VERSION', None)}\n"
     90             f"Pillow version: {__version__}"
     91         )

ImportError: dlopen(/Users/moi/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.cpython-311-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libtiff.5.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/moi/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.cpython-311-darwin.so
     Reason: image not found
```

after countless uninstallations and reinstallations it still didnt work .

i suddenly remembered that when i first installed anaconda and was still experimenting with python , i didnt install all my libraries with conda command , some were installed with pip and so was the case for the pillow library, so i uninstalled pillow using conda :

```
conda uninstall pillow
```

and reinstalled it using pip :

```
pip install pillow
```

needless to say : it worked!!

Ps: im using MacOs and this actually solved my problem with pillow and matplotlib cause it uses a dependancy of pillow i gess , anyways HOPE THIS HELPS!

edit: if all of this does not work , i recommend reinstalling Jupyter notebook

```
conda uninstall jupyter

conda install jupyter
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same error after reinstalling Miniconda and setting up a new virtual environment (Python 3.10). It occurred when importing Seaborn (and therefore Matplotlib).

For me just uninstalling and reinstalling Pillow worked:

```
conda uninstall pillow
conda install pillow
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, just to save other readers' time

```
conda uninstall pillow
```

will downgrade plenty of packages, including python. In my case:

```
python    3.12.2-h2628c8c_0_cpython --> 3.9.18-h4de0772_1_cpython
```